# Client not able to contact the web-server over wireless n/w - through CODE

Tags: c#, wifi, getresponsestream

```
//code in the client
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.5/test");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I have a LAN setup with two machines in my workgroup.
 - 192.168.0.1 (that's the client)
 - 192.168.0.5 (that's the web server)

The above piece of code works perfectly fine in a simple wired network.

When I run it on a wireless network, i.e. with the network setup using a wi-fi router instead of a switch, the code doesn't work - it gets stuck on GetResponse.

Strangely, when I open up my browser and type - http://192.168.0.5/test - it works...the page shows up!

What am I missing? Why is the client not able to contact the server through code?

Comment: Is Windows Firewall turned on? If so, try shutting it off to test.

Comment: no, firewall is turned off in all situations to test. still isn't working

Comment: Do you have a proxy defined in Windows / your browser?

Comment: no proxies...and remember - same network setup works with a wired network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "gets stuck" do you mean it hangs?

Is this the first request in the program, or are there others? One frequent cause of "hanging" web requests is failure to close/dispose web responses. Once you've made two (by default) requests to the same server, you'd have to wait for the responses to be finalized.

I don't know why this would only affect you in the case of a wireless network connection instead of wired, but if you're not closing web responses (preferably with `using` statements) I'd recommend fixing that to start with.

Next up, trace the network with [WireShark](http://wireshark.org). That should make it really easy to see whether the request is actually sent, whether a response comes back etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir.

By "gets stuck" , I do mean it hangs - eventually moves to the catch block with the timeout exception.

This is the first request that the client sends, so no question of unclosed web responses.

I will try Wireshark and see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Righto. If it does make the request but doesn't get a response back, I'd compare the request from .NET with the request from the browser. I don't expect it'll be fun looking at it in a huge amount of detail, but it should help eventually.